# Naming convention for number range

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

What are some possible ways to name a variable representing a range of numbers? For example, I am working on a metrics application that displays the age of certain items in a person's queue. They are measured in

1. 0-50 days
2. 51-100 days
3. 100+ days

I've thought about spelling the range out: `zeroToFifty`, `range0-50`. I've also considered naming them by "sections": `first`, `second`, `third`, but this doesn't prove to be very descriptive at all. What have you guys done to represent number ranges?

Comment: All I can think of is: whatever you want, but choose one and stick with it.

Comment: zeroToFifty, fiftyOneToHundred and hundredPlus get my vote.

Comment: The best answer I can give is name them in a way that will make sense to you 6 months down the road, or the next person working on it.

Comment: What about `range0000To0050`, `range0051To0100`, `range0101Onwards`? Though I would hate if someone told me how to name my variables >.<

Comment: I'd probably go with `range0To50` but it's a personal preference. Be consistent though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, a name like ZeroToFifty isn't really very descriptive, hardly any better than `if (number < 50)`. Variable names should provide more information if possible, while still being brief.

Second, I'd advise *against* embedding the numerical values into the constants - if you decide that the bottom range goes to 60 then a ZeroToFifty naming won't match any more. It will be much easier to adjust the values later if you don't have to refactor a name change throughout your codebase. Also, users of the constant probably don't care about 50, they care about "is it young or old?".

So you need to think *"what do these number ranges represent"*?

It depends on the usage, but you may find `Young, Mature, Old` works well for your case, as it describes the age of the item (and thus gives you strong clues about the meaning or usage of the value). Or maybe `Modern, Classic, Vintage`. Or `Baby, Child, Adult`. (If they "fit" the usage you have in mind).

In C# if you use an enumerated type, the typename must always be used, and that also can help clarify the meaning: `ItemAge.Young/Mature/Old` or `TimeInQueue.Short/Medium/Long`.

Comment: I know this wasn't the original intent of the question, but what would you suggest for a case where there are many ranges? 1-10, 11 - 20, ..., 140-150? Range1, Range2...?

Comment: @Jeff: It depends on the number of ranges. If there are more than about 5 ranges it starts to be difficult to find enough names to form a coherent list, so a more generalised numerical sequence is easier (Age01, Age02, Age03...). However, when coding with lots of ranges it is often much easier to abandon enumerated types and start using a Map/Look Up table that converts between a simple index value (1,2,3) and a range (1-10, 11-30, 31-73). Then the importance of naming falls more on the variables (ageIndex versus ageRange, etc)